# Can I start youtube live stream with the use of previously uploaded my youtube video?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I previously uploaded many video files.

How do I use my previous uploads in a new live stream?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible, you can not create a new live stream from existing YouTube videos.

What you can do is collect all of your videos, create a new live event, and stream your videos via RTMP to YouTube's ingestion endpoint.